# Swift Mailer in Yii Configuration

Tags: yii

I want to send email with swift Mailer,
but i don't want to send only one email.
I want to send form data from my member model.

so how can i config this?

```
->setTo(array('recipient@example.com' => 'Recipient Name'))
```

I am using Yii 1.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$email = Email::model()->findByPk(1);
```

and

```
 ->setTo(array($email->email => $email->name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load all members and using php foreach() and send email to each user separatly. In Yii2 there is also possibility to use model(object) like array

```
foreach($this->getMembers()->each() as $member){
 ...
 ->setTo($member->email)
 ...
}
```